# How could I make my Haskell app run in Docker?

Tags: docker, haskell

I am trying to dockerize a Haskell app.

Here is the content of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM haskell:8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN cabal update

RUN cabal v2-build

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["runapp.sh"]
```

`runapp.sh` is a file that's present in the filesystem and being copied to the image with `COPY . .`. Image is built fine, without problems - I see all the dependencies being successfully installed during the image building phase and the app getting successfully built. But for some reason Docker cannot find `runapp.sh` on `docker run` even if I specify it with `CMD ["app/runapp.sh"]`:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "app/runapp.sh": stat app/runapp.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

If I specify no `CMD` trying to test execution of the commands with `docker exec` and launch the container with `docker run`, I get the following error even though the app was built fine on the image building phase:

```
Module.hs:9:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Aeson’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Version (from base-4.14.3.0)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
9 | import qualified Data.Aeson   as JSON
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, two modules loaded.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /app/.ghci
*Initial> Leaving GHCi.
```

How could I make my Haskell app run in Docker?

PS. The content of the `runapp.sh` file:

```
./dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/AppName/x/app/build/app/app
```

Comment: What’s the path to `runapp.sh` relative to the context? Seems like you might want either `CMD ["./runapp.sh"]` or `CMD ["/app/runapp.sh"]`.

Comment: I am getting an error: `exec /app/runapp.sh: exec format error` if I do `CMD ["/app/runapp.sh"]`. I tried `CMD ["./runapp.sh"]` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: `CMD ["sh", "runapp.sh"]` then, and you should probably add a shebang.